# Mutable references rust

Tags: rust, reference, mutable

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 42;
    let y = &x;
    *y = 5;
}
```

This does not compile. Why does it have to be a `&mut` to `x`?
In my understanding, the reference (i.e. address where the value of `x` is stored) does not change, only the value stored on that address. And `x` is `mut`.

Does compile:

```
fn main() {
    let mut x = 42;
    let y = &mut x;
    *y = 5;
}
```

Comment: [DerefMut](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html) vs [Deref](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html)

Comment: Hint: How are you going to modify a non-`mut` reference? `&x` is read-only. `&mut x` can be mutated.

Comment: In your first example, `y` takes a shared borrow of `x`; it is a fundamental of Rust's memory safety model that values cannot be mutated while they are (non-exclusively) borrowed.  In your second example, the borrow is exclusive.

Comment: Maybe it helps if you consider that this compiles: `let x = 42; let y = &x`. Now, if something like `*y = 5` were allowed, what's to stop you from modifying a non-`mut` x?

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of `&mut` is a reference through which a value can be mutated, rather than a reference which itself can be mutated. `&` denotes a reference through which a value cannot be mutated. A reference which itself can be mutated would be written something like `let mut y = &x;` (though in practice this is not common).

> In my understanding ... the reference (i.e. address where the value of x is stored) ...

I think the confusion here stems from the fact that a reference is not quite the same thing as a memory address or pointer. It is more conceptual and makes more guarantees - such as the fact that the reference will always point to a valid object of the given type.